# Access 'scrollLeft' property in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, scroll, drag

I'm facing a problem with div property attributes when I convert my code from basic HTML and JS to react

the old code and the Desired result would be like this    :

https://codepen.io/fadeomar/project/editor/DVWGjd

now when starting to convert this project to react it cant change the value of scrollLeft property

my question is how I can change the value of `scrollLeft` for a certain element in react, all I got when I searched this issue that setting event listener to the whole window object, not for a specific element in DOM

I thought to use reusable component for Drag and Scroll and here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export class ScrollDrag extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ref = React.createRef();
    this.state = {
      isScrolling: false,
      clientX: 0,
      scrollX: 0,
    };
  }

  onMouseDown = e => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, isScrolling: true, 
     clientX: e.clientX });
  };

  onMouseUp = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, isScrolling: false });
  };

  onMouseMove = e => {
    const { clientX, scrollX } = this.state;
    if (this.state.isScrolling) {
      this.ref.current.scrollLeft = scrollX + e.clientX - clientX;
      this.setState({scrollX: scrollX + e.clientX - clientX, clientX: e.clientX})
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { rootClass } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.ref}
        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
        className={rootClass}
      >
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
            React.Children.only(child))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ScrollDrag.defaultProps = {
  ref: { current: {} },
  rootClass: '',
};

ScrollDrag.propTypes = {
  ref: PropTypes.object,
  rootClass: PropTypes.string,
  children: PropTypes.string,
};

export default ScrollDrag;
```

then I use it as an heir order component in the app

this is my try : 
https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-butterfly-ndp6z?file

Any help to make this works be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated answer**

You were scrolling the wrong element. I removed the wrappers from the items and tweaked the css. I also had to reverse the polarity of the scrolling. Now it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-tree-s8miv?file=/src/DragScroll.js

**Original answer to original (now edited) question**

The error is caused by the fact that you're not using `ref` you've created in this component:

```
render() {
    const { ref, rootClass } = this.props; // <-- this is wrong
    return (
      <div
        ref={ref}
        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
        className={rootClass}
      >
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
            React.Children.only(child))}
      </div>
    );
```

It should just be like this:

```
render() {
    const { rootClass } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        ref={this.ref}
        onMouseDown={this.onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={this.onMouseUp}
        onMouseMove={this.onMouseMove}
        className={rootClass}
      >
        {React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
            React.Children.only(child))}
      </div>
    );
```

Comment: thanks for replay will, actually the error disappear but the didn't work, I consoled the scrollLeft property still 0 it didn't change I wonder why, I'll edit the question

Comment: I suspect your maths is off - `this.ref.current.scrollLeft = scrollX + e.clientX - clientX`... if `e.clientX === clientX` then your scrollLeft will always be zero. I suggest you `console.log `it.

Comment: hay @will I've consoled the operation and it works as expected but the problem is the offestScroll don't apply to the div